# Why is there no command for gunicorn

Tags: python, python-3.x, gunicorn

I ran this:

```
pip3 install gunicorn
```

Then I tried to run gunicorn, but I was told there was no such command. If I do this:

```
ls -al /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/
```

I see this:

```
.
..
app
arbiter.py
argparse_compat.py
_compat.py
config.py
debug.py
errors.py
glogging.py
http
__init__.py
instrument
pidfile.py
__pycache__
reloader.py
selectors.py
six.py
sock.py
systemd.py
util.py
workers
```

I was thinking I could create a symbolic link and store it here:

```
/usr/local/bin/
```

But what would I link? It seems as if there is no actual gunicorn command?

If I look here:

https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn

There is no file called "gunicorn". Likewise if I look here:

https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/gunicorn

As near as I can see, there is no file called "gunicorn". So how are we suppose to call this from the command line?

Comment: https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/master/setup.py#L105

Comment: The script is just called "gunicorn".  Make sure pip is installing scripts into a place which is listed in your PATH.

Comment: What I'm saying is that there is no script called "gunicorn" in that folder.

Comment: Can you post the contents of your gunicorn script? I can copy and paste it to my machine.

Comment: Sure - well, it just looks like the usual setuptools console script entry point.  https://hastebin.com/golibamoja.py  You will need to adjust the shebang to list the path to the interpreter with which you installed `gunicorn`.

Comment: you could find out the path of your `pip3` with `which pip3`, and take a look at that dir.

Comment: @wim -- You are saying that I should put in a symbolic link to the setup file and that will work as a CLI command?

Comment: @wim -- I don't have a script called "gunicorn". I ran "pip install gunicorn" and that gave me a folder called "gunicorn" and that folder is full of code. But there is no file called "gunicorn" so I'm not able to call the command "gunicorn"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have apt (or apt-get):

```sh
$ sudo apt install gunicorn3

$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gunicorn3 /usr/bin/gunicorn
```

You may want to remove the old gunicorn package first:

```sh
$ sudo apt remove gunicorn
```

Check where gunicorn3 has been installed (just in case):

```
$ whereis gunicorn3
```

Comment: That's right! I've tried to install it using `sudo apt install python3-gunicorn` but it didn't create executable on path, and this command did! Thanks!

Comment: @Emil this way Gunicorn is using the default Python version (3.6 in my case). But what to do if you need to start Gunicorn with Python 3.7 and avoid using virtualenv?

Answer (score 2):

You can install gunicorn in two ways,

If you want to install OS level try this for ubuntu `sudo apt install gunicorn`
or pip style `pip install gunicorn` - this is suggestable

To check If it is installed try below commands

```
$ pip show gunicorn
Name: gunicorn
Version: 19.9.0
Summary: WSGI HTTP Server for UNIX
Home-page: http://gunicorn.org
Author: Benoit Chesneau
Author-email: benoitc@e-engura.com
License: MIT
Location: /home/<user>/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by:
```

Let me know If my understanding on your question is right.

Comment: I don't think you read my question. The first thing I explain is that I'd already used `pip` and it did not work for me.

Comment: Install (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-anaconda-python-distribution-on-ubuntu-16-04) anaconda, which is very easy and handy to use and you wont get this kind of problem again. 
once done run this commands

```conda create --name env_name python=3.5```
```source activate env_name```
```pip install gunicorn```
thats it, now you should be able to see gunicorn at ```Location: /home/<your_user>/anaconda3/envs/env_name/bin/gunicorn``` location.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to solve this problem:->
just add the path of gunicorn location or find the path and execute with the path.

If you're working with virtualenv then:- don't install the gunicorn for root just use the `pip install gunicorn`.
if you already installed the gunicorn for root then just remove it by `sudo apt remove gunicorn`

you're in your virtualenv then just chek the location of the gunicorn by:-

`pip show gunicorn`
This will give you the details including the path of gunicorn.
something like this:-

> /home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages.

now either you can add this path or just execute it as:-

```
~/.local/bin/gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 <projectname>.wsgi
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using *virtualenv* then `gunicorn` is created in

> /path_to_your_env/bin/gunicorn

So whenever you try to use gunicorn you need to load the virtualenv first and then gunicorn command would execute.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working. That was what I did the first time, and it did not work. I was inside a virtualenv, I ran "pip3 install gunicorn" and afterwards the gunicorn was not in the path.

Comment: you activated the virtualenv right? could you try _pip install gunicorn_ rather than pip3

Comment: I haven't been able to get virtualenv to work. I'm going to try a global install. I did run "pip3 install gunicorn" and got it installed at `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn` . But when I try to invoke it in my Django app, I get the same old message "gunicorn not found". Same is true even when I explicitly add `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn` to the PYTHONPATH. How do I add this to my path?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone reaches this page, and has not yet found an answer (it happened with me), please check to make sure you have exported both

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin
```

and

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

to your PATH variable.

I am working with MacOS 10.14.6 and Python 3.6.5, so apt-get was not really an option for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need `pip install gunicorn`.

Answer (score -1):

You should use

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/python3/bin
```